# (pointer-to) error....*sigh*

Tags: c++, pointers

```
// program assignment 2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double percentconverter;
    int playerinput;
    int years;
    double intrates;
    double answer;

    cout << " Enter initial amount:" << endl;
    cin  >> playerinput;

    cout << "Enter number of years:" << endl;
    cin  >> years;

    cout << "Enter interest rate (percent per year):" << endl;
    cin  >> percentconverter;

    intrates = percentconverter / 100;
answer = playerinput * (1 + intrates) ^ years;

    return 0;
}
```

ok at line "answer = playerinput * (1 + intrates) ^ years;" i get a little red line underneath playerinput, it says pointer-to function somthing....i don't understand y i get that error, also my assignment to "Write a program that calculates how much money you’ll end up with if you invest an
amount of money at a fixed interest rate, compounded yearly." the equations i'm confident enough are right and when i run the completed program it will run the way it should, if i'm wrong in the equation feel free to leave feed back. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The little hat (^) isn't exponentiation in C++, I think you mean:

```
answer = pow( playerinput * (1 + intrates), years );
```

which will raise "playerinput * (1 + intrates)" to the power "years".

Oh, FYI ^ = XOR, bitwise that is.

Comment: thanks alot trying it now....nad thanks for the very fast response, i'm a noob in training :)

Comment: `pow( playerinput * (1 + intrates), years );` is not the same as `playerinput * pow( (1 + intrates), years );`

Comment: That's true, but mine retained his original logic. It would multiply "playerinput * (1 + intrates)" first - either because of * precedence or left-to-right, take your pick - then do the exponentiation. Assuming '^' was the exponentiation operator. I have no way of knowing what he wants to calculate, only that he didn't understand why the XOR operator was giving him an error.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is not pow its bitwise xor so you should use pow instead

```
#include <math.h>
[...]
answer = playerinput * pow ((1 + intrates), years);
[...]
```

Comment: thanks this one work the other gave me i retard number but this gave me the correct one thanks alot :)